# Можете объяснить что делает Inc

Tags: pascal

Я понимаю что inc это прибавление (+1), но что оно делает в этой программе:

```
var 
  A, B : array [1..30] of integer;
  s, d : integer;
begin
  for s := 1 to 30 do
    begin
      A[s]:= random(167)-99;
      write(A[s], ' ' );            
      if A[s] mod 2 = 0 then
        begin
          inc(d);
          B[d] := A[s];
        end;         
    end;
  writeln;
  for s := 1 to d do
    write(B[s], ' ');
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Тэкс ну тут получается два массива и начинаем заполнять первый рандомными числами. Дальше проверяем если только что полученное число четное то мы прибавляем к d единицу и записываем это число во второй массив. Получается у тебя d выступает в роле индекса и его необходимо увеличивать на единицу чтобы заполнять массив. И в итоге у тебя массив B будет содержать только четные числа из массива A.

Answer (score 0):

> Я понимаю что inc это прибавление (+1), но что оно делает в этой программе:

Он считает сколько раз сработало условие в if, то есть количество чётных элементов массива A.

А так как массив B индексируется с единицы, то количество совпадает с номером последнего элемента, поэтому это количество можно использовать ещё и как индекс последнего элемента.

PS переменную d желательно явно инициализировать нулём перед первым циклом.